# how do used dynamic query in stored procedure if i want to pass multiple values in one parameter

Tags: mysql

Below is sample stored procedure :

In this , I want to pass modes as (1,2,(1,2)) and user_types as (1,2 or 0 for both (1,2))

how do I write this type of situation

```
    DELIMITER ;

    CREATE PROCEDURE `Statistics`
    (
       IN Start_Date DATE,
       IN END_Date DATE,
       IN Modes  int,
       IN User_Type INT
    )
    BEGIN

    -- User_Type = (0 0r 1 or 2)
    -- modes=(1 or 2 or (1,2))


    IF (User_Type=0)
    THEN
            select * from table 
            where modes in (1 or 2 or (1,2)) AND Dates BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
       GROUP BY  Dates;
    ELSE
    IF(User_Type=1)
    THEN
              select * from table 
            where modes in (1 or 2 or (1,2)) AND Dates BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date

    ELSE
    IF (User_Type=2)
    THEN
                select * from table 
            where modes in (1 or 2 or (1,2)) AND Dates BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date

    END IF;

     END IF;
    END IF;
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is not efficient - but you can use `FIND_IN_SET(table.modes, Modes)`. BTW: Maybe you should use different names for the parameter and the column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Prepared Statements! You can read about them here:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-prepared-statement.aspx

Comment: I dont want to use cursors , I want to use dynamic query ,how do I use it

Comment: I think you mean Prepared Statements! If not iam sorry, Maybe this helps you: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-prepared-statement.aspx